# How do I get/install Linux firmware for my EW-7727In wireless adapter?

Tags: wifi, drivers, firmware, hardware-compatibility

I have an Edimax EW-7727In which I want to use with a box running Debian  Stretch over a 4.2.0.1 Linux kernel. But - without installing anything special, my taskbar widget tells me I'm missing the right firmware for this wireless adapter.

I tried downloading and building from the [Manufacturer's website](http://www.edimax.com/en/support_detail.php?pd_id=257&pl1_id=1&pl2_id=44), but:

1. Build failed with the default configuration
2. The readme had confusing instructions regarding building the thing to by managed by NetworkManager, and I couldn't even tell whether I want that or not.

I was thinking maybe there's some precompiled firmware package available, but no package names says "edimax" or "ralink".

**Notes:**

- I would rather not mess with the driver source code myself
- I don't care about maximizing card performance or utilizing special features such as WPS or what-have-you

Comment: Not using Debian Strech, but this might help you: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/firmware-ralink

Comment: @tastytea: Hmm. Crafty. I'll try it and report whether that works.

Comment: That package is non-free, so you will probably have to edit your sources.list file if you haven't already.